# vagrant box add laravel/homestead not working

Tags: laravel, homestead

First time i'm installing homestead on my windows 10 machine but when i run
**vagrant box add laravel/homestead**
command in gitbash it gives me segmentation fault error.I'm using vagrant 2.0.1 version .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkBr6.png)

Comment: Have you installed Virtual Box and Vagrant first? [Installation steps](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead#installation-and-setup).

Comment: What's your vagrant version? Run `vagrant --version`

Comment: .I uninstall vargrant version 2.0.1 and install 1.8 and it worked .Thanks for replying @Tpojka